# How update the first element of an array in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning NodeJs and MongoDb and I will create a photo album.
I encounter a problem with mongoDB.

In fact, after uploading a picture, I push new pictures into the database like this :

```
AlbumPicture.update({album:'album1'}, {$push: {pictures:file_name}}, function(err, data){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('Database Updated');
});
```

The problem is : the 'row' : pictures is an array() so when i push new data, the first element of this array (id:[0]) is not set.

Example :

```
{
  picture:
    [
      "", // Not Set ??
      "1.jpg",
      "2.jpg"
    ]
}
```

How I can update the first element of this array and next push other data after ?

I tested with these portion of code but it doesn't seem to work and it is not beautiful.

```
AlbumPicture.find({album:'album1'}).exec(function(err, data){

  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }

  if(data[0].pictures[0] == '')
  {
    AlbumPicture.update({album:'album1'}, {$set: {'pictures[0]':file_name}}, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }

      console.log('Database Updated @ 0');
    });
  }
  else
  {
    AlbumPicture.update({album:'album1'}, {$push: {pictures:file_name}}, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }

      console.log('Database Updated');
    });
  }
});
```

**UPDATE : I create my collection like this :**

```
var albumData = {
  album : 'album1',
  pictures : ''
};

var AlbumPicture = new AlbumPicture(albumData);

AlbumPicture.save(function(error, data){
 if(error){
  console.log(error);
 }
 else
 {
  console.log('Album Created');
  res.json('created');
 }
});
```

Comment: It looks like when you AlbumPicture is being created with the pictures array having [0] ="". How are you creating the AlbumPicture?

Comment: @DominicScanlan Like this : `var albumData = {
  album : 'album1',
  pictures : ''
};

var AlbumPicture = new AlbumPicture(albumData);

AlbumPicture.save(function(error, data){
 if(error){
  console.log(error);
 }
 else
 {
  console.log('Album Created');
  res.json('created');
 }
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set pictures to an empty array you shouldn't have a value at index 0.

`var albumData = { album : 'album1', pictures : [] };`